# How to join data frames with keeping only matching ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, join, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
id   value
a1   12
a2   15
a3   17
```

```
id   value1
a1   22
a2   58
a7   10
```

I want to join them by column id keeping only matching one:

```
id   value    value1
a1    12       22
a2    15       58
```

How to do that? I tried pd.merge but it keeps all id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.merge` and `inner`:

**Example of dataframe**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a1','a2', 'a3'],
                    'value':[12, 15, 17]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a1','a2', 'a7'],
                    'value':[22, 58, 10]})
```

**code**

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = ['id'])
merged_df.columns = ["id", "value", "value1"]
```

**Result**

```
   id  value  value1
0  a1     12      22
1  a2     15      58
```

If you want to change index as *id*, you can use `pd.set_index('id')`